# How to get each youtube url from textarea in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, textarea

Please solve my problem.
I have a textarea. In this textarea i enter multiple youtube video url(line by line). My question is how to store each url as array using javascript.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could accept an answer that help you the most.

Answer (score 0):

This code should works, I split the `textarea` value based on line break as you mentioned (line by line).

```js
 let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
    let arr = []
    function check(){
      arr = textarea.value.split('\n')
      console.log(arr)
    }
```

```html
<textarea>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqboAI-Vk-U&t=22s
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA</textarea>
 <button onclick = 'check()'>Check</button>
```

Comment: Very very thanks. Big brother.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use regex like this (`textareaValue` contains the value of textarea):

```js
const matches = textareaValue.match(/\bhttp(s)?:\/\/(www.)?youtu(be|.be).*\b/gm);
```

The `matches` will be an array of the urls that start with `http(s)://(www.)youtube`